# When using Import-CSV into Variable in PowerShell, no information returned

Tags: powershell, import-csv

Very useful - When i was Using `$CSVInfo = Import-CSV c:\datatable.csv`

Nothing was being returned when i opened the variable from the command line. Why is this? Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was opening and editing the CSV in Excel. After being stumped for quite a while I Opened it in `NotePad ++` and checked it over. The `Encoding` was `UTF-8`

I changed this to `ANSI`, and, Voila! The Data was returned when asking the command line what was contained within `$CSVInfo`

Comment: You don't have to change the encoding of your file, just use the `-encoding` parameter of the function: `Import-Csv -Path C:\datatable.csv -Encoding UTF8`

Comment: What is the default encoding then resulting in the csv not being imported if you do not specify an encoding type?

Comment: The Documentations says (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-5.1): "The default is ASCII."